# Python scripts automáticos Unitest

Tags: python

quiero hacer unos test de pruebas para un fichero de condiciones. Dar valor a una variables y después de esperar 5 segundos comprobar que la salida es la correcta. He leído que en Python hay un módulo de Unitest ¿Alguien puede mostrarme un ejemplo de como estructurar mis test y como funciona este módulo?

Esto es lo que llevo hecho de momento:

```
import unittest

class TestCheckConditions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_semaforo1(self):
        for line in open('FicheroEntrada.csv','r'):
            semaforo = line.find('D12032')
            if semaforo.split(";")[11] = 1:
               outfile.write(line)

    def test_semaforo2(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

#Ejecutar todos los test
#unittest.main()

outfile = open("salida.txt","w")
unittest.main()
close.outfile

close.infile1
close.infile2
```

Entre mis problemas está que no sé como llamar solamente al test_semaforo1 dentro de la clase TestCheckConditions. Es decir pasar solamente este test, con unittest.main() me pasa todos los test a la vez.

Otro tema es que tengo que buscar en que linea está D12032 y comprobar que es el valor que quiero. Este código no me funciona aún.

Comment: Hola AlberM: ¿has hecho alguna búsqueda al respecto? Hay cantidad de ejemplos por internet que podrían serte muy útiles. Échale un vistazo y edita la pregunta con cuestiones más concretas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguien que sabe (mucho) más que yo me recomendó utilizar [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) en lugar del módulo de unittest.

La principal ventaja que tiene es que su sintaxis es muchísima más clara. Por ejemplo, así se escribiría un test:

```
# contenido en test_ejemplo.py
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_funcion():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

Para realizar los tests, basta con escribir pytest en la ventana de comandos o terminal:

> $ pytest
>
> ======= test session starts ========
>
> platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.4, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0 rootdir: $REGENDOC_TMPDIR,
>   inifile: collected 1 items
>
> test_ejemplo.py F
>
> ======= FAILURES ========
>
> _______ test_funcion ________
>
> ```
> def test_funcion():
> ```
>
> > ```
> >   assert func(3) == 5 E       assert 4 == 5 E        +  where 4 = func(3)
> > ```
>
> test_ejemplo.py:5: AssertionError
>   ======= 1 failed in 0.12 seconds ========

No acabo de entender cómo quieres estructurar los tests que utilizas, pero quizás te sirvan estos dos ejemplos de la documentación [i](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#asserting-that-a-certain-exception-is-raised), [ii](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#grouping-multiple-tests-in-a-class)

Por último, quizás te sea más cómodo separar los tests y trabajar con `try`/`except` y `with` usando algo [así](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement):

```
try:
    f = open('foo.txt')
except IOError:
    print('error')
else:
    with f:
        print f.readlines()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Simplemente tengo que hacer una serie de test forzando valores de un fichero A y ver después de unos segundos el valor en la salida B. Y no sé como estructura las pruebas, en plan: